# An optimization problem about number series

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Given $m>0$, we want to minimize
$$
\sum_{k=1}^r a_k \log b_k 
$$
for arbitrary increasing number series $a_k\geq 1$ and $b_k\geq 1$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_k}=1
$$
and $r$ satisfies
$$
a_rb_r\geq m.
$$
It should be a function of $m$. It seems $\log m$ is not reachable.

Comment: And what prevents you from having $b_1=0$?

Comment: What are variables and what are parameters?

Comment: @fedja Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alekseyev $m$ is the parameter, the rest are variables.

Comment: Should it be $\sum_{k=1}^{r} \frac{1}{a_k}<1$ or why do you care about $a_k$ for $k>r$?

Comment: Also, why not just take $r=b_1=1$ and $a_1=m$ ?

Comment: @Alekseyev $r$ is determined by $a_k$ and $b_k$. $b_k$ is increasing, therefore $b_1$ can not be $1$.